# Using the .NET 3.5 Entity Framework how can I save an entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have for example a table called Client.

Usually in .NET 4 I would do:

```
dbEntities.Clients.AddObject(myClienteObject);
```

but in .NET 3.5 I cannot find this method, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entities.AddToClients(newClient);
```

Would do the job I guess? After that you ofcourse call

```
entities.SaveChanges();
```